# Is there a REST API for Azure App Services

Tags: rest, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

Looking through the [Azure Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt420159.aspx) I can't find any references to the REST API (or any API) for Azure App Services, Service Plans, Web apps etc

Is there a REST API for Azure App Services?

I have seen [Are there no Rest Api for deploying Azure Websites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16753014/are-there-no-rest-api-for-deploying-azure-websites) But there have been a huge number of changes to Azure since 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE - 01-Mar-2017**

The answer below is obsolete as when the answer was provided the REST API was not documented. It is now :). The REST API documentation is available here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/.

---

<del>I'm sure that there's a REST API. It's just that it is not documented yet.</del>

<del>Whenever I need to find REST API for something that has not been documented, one thing I normally do is run `Azure PowerShell Cmdlets` in debug mode. It tells me all the information I need (though I must say that it is not a substitute for documentation).</del>

Comment: Yeah I do that too! It would just be nice if there was some actual specification for such things. (I'm not sure we're allowed to use the words Azure and documentation together in the same sentence anymore)

Comment: I completely agree with you. However at the same time I kind of sympathize with Azure documentation team. Considering the pace with which Azure is evolving, it's extremely hard to keep up with the documentation (though it's not an excuse IMHO).

Comment: At the same time, its not like they're short of cash! Employ more people, get them involved earlier. Write something that gives us automated documentation so we know how to interact with the stuff. (/rant!) but thanks for the answer - I do suspect this will be as good as it gets

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by running the cmdlets in debug mode please?

Comment: @DanO'Leary Please see my answer to your question. To answer this specific question, you just run the Cmdlet and add `-Debug` switch to the Cmdlet.

Answer (score 6):

yes, there is REST API for all azure resources. and they all thru Azure Resource Manger

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn790568.aspx

to learn about the API, there is also a portal for you to play with https://resources.azure.com

**Update:**

Azure resources are managed by ARM API

e.g if you want to delete a website, you will make bellow http request against your site

```
DELETE https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscription id}/resourceGroups/{resource group}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/{site name}?api-version=2015-08-01
```

https://resources.azure.com is a great place for you to learn about ARM REST API, resource structure, what uri to use and what payload to be expected.

Comment: The link you mentioned is incorrect as it is for Azure Service Management API. What OP is looking for is API documentation for Azure App Service which is part of Azure Resource Manager.

Comment: The link you posted is also the parent link to the one I posted! I am specifically looking for a REST API for App Services, and references to that and as useful as Resource Explorer is, it doesn't give a complete view of the API, it doesn't specify what can / can't be set or what parameters are needed to do so.

Comment: The basic stuff is all well and good - and pretty easy to discover. but when you start doing more complex tasks, it is much more difficult to find answers - for instance, under `Microsoft.Web/certificates` I'd like to set `keyVaultId` Is there some REST API documentation - or place to find how to do that. AFAIK there isn't, which was the purpose of the question.

Comment: @MichaelB i see. https://resources.azure.com, there is "documentation" tab for each resource. hope that will address some of your issue. There is also a template sample repository, https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates, hopefully you can find enough sample for your needs. if none of those helps, try to use https://portal.azure.com to config your resource and go back to https://resources.azure.com to see the payload, hopefully this revers-enginering will help you to find the payload. if none of these help. Post question to SO or MSDN forum, we are here to help.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any up-to-date documentation at the moment. What I recommend you do in the meantime is to take a look at Azure Resource Explorer:

https://resources.azure.com

Log in with your Azure credentials and navigate to a subscription you have which contains some App Service resources (web apps, etc.). From there, you can browse your resource groups and find everything else in that subscription.

You'll notice that as you navigate around, you'll notice that the right-hand pane displays the URL of the resource and you can even issue GET/PUT/POST/DELETE commands against those resources using the buttons provided. Under that, you will see the actual JSON payload associated with that resource. You can use these all as hints for how you would construct a REST API call.

In some cases, you can get some actual documentation on the various fields if you click on the Documentation button for a particular resource you're viewing. This doesn't always seem to work, however. If you're feeling like going down the advanced path, you can also get the official swagger documentation for the App Service REST API in Github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/master/arm-web/2015-08-01/swagger/service.json